# Java Project Build and run problem with FX

Tags: java, javafx

i'm trying run a project with this architecture...
[image: Project architecture]

And, when i press "Run" button the code gives me this error...

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:465)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:901)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper (in unnamed module @0x709a3ba3) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.util.Utils (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.util to unnamed module @0x709a3ba3
    at com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper.<clinit>(FXMLLoaderHelper.java:38)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.<clinit>(FXMLLoader.java:2135)
    at ui.Main.start(Main.java:32)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application ui.Main
```

My code of my Main...

```
package ui;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import model.FIBAManager;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main extends Application {

    private static final String FOLDER = "fxml/";

    private FIBAManager manager;
    private MainGUIController MGC;
    private EmergentGUIController EGC;

    public Main() throws IOException {
        manager = new FIBAManager();
        EGC = new EmergentGUIController(manager);
        MGC = new MainGUIController(manager, EGC);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage window) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(FOLDER + "MainWindow.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setController(MGC);
        Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, null);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.setTitle("");
        window.show();
    }

}
```

And i have this run cofiguration:

```
--module-path "C:\Users\Giova\Downloads\javafx-sdk-17.0.0.1\lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls
```

I need help to solve this problem and run the project please

Comment: Don't post images of text. Post the complete stack trace, formatted as code.

Comment: Do you have "=" sign after --module-path?

Comment: @stuck Shouldn't matter; both `--module-path <path>` and `--module-path=<path>` are accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using fxml so you need to add the fxml module, otherwise it will not be visible for use:

```
--add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

See the openjfx.io documentation titled [Run HelloWorld using JavaFX SDK](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx).

Example execution command for Linux from that source (modified to add the `javafx.fxml` module):

```
java --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml HelloFX
```

---

Alternately, you can define a module-info.java file which requires javafx.fxml and any other modules required for your application.  See: [Understanding Java 9 modules](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html).

```
module <your module name> {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;

    opens <your package> to javafx.fxml;
    exports <your package>;
}
```

Substituting your info for:

- `module <your module name>` any name you want, but best to put it as the name of the primary package of your app, e.g. `com.example.javafx.myapppackage`.  Follow [Java 9 module naming conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50736107/naming-convention-for-java-9-modules).
- `opens <your package> to javafx.fxml` a package which uses fxml (opens is required to allow the fxml package to reflect on your code).
- `exports <your package>` a package you want to make visible (via export) to users of your application's module code; e.g. the package which contains the class in your appliction with a `main(args)` method.

---

Or, you can ignore the module system using the hack provided in [mipa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69965385/1155209), as mipa does have a very good point about the additional complexity involved in using the module system.  It is not a supported configuration by the JavaFX developers, but will likely work OK for your app.

Answer (score 2):

Just append this line to the file containing your Main class.

```
class MainLauncher {public static void main(String[] args) {Main.main(args);}}
```

Then put all your dependencies on the classpath (also JavaFX) and in your command line remove everything that is related to modules. Then launch the main from the MainLauncher class and be happy. You'll see a little warning. Just ignore it. This module stuff is simply unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a jdk created by Liberica that has JavaFX integrated into it so you can compile with `javac` and run with `java`.  Make sure you download the "Full" JDK.  This eliminates a lot of headaches.